# How to count number of time a particular item is added?

Tags: asp.net, database

I am working on the web application developed in ASP.Net using C#. Allong with other feature, there is a feature which allow users to add various items to their personal list. The database tables relevant to above features are:

```
-------------------------
| Item                  |
-------------------------
| ItemId (Primary Key)  |
| . . . & other attribs |
-------------------------

---------------------------
|List                     |
---------------------------
|ListId (Primary Key)     |
|. . . and other attribs  |
---------------------------
```

Since there is many to many relationship among above two table (i.e One Item is added in many lists and one list contains many items) So i create third table for that

```
---------------------------------
|ItemList                       |
---------------------------------
|ItemId (Foreign Key)           |
|ListId (Foreign Key)           |
|. . . and other Attributes     |
---------------------------------
```

Now, I in need to maintain track that how many times a certain item is added in the list. In order to acheive this i have two possible options

1. I add a new attribute in Item table and increment that value with one every time when a particular item is added to a certain list.
2. The second option is that whenever i need to know that how many
   times a particular item is added in the list, then i will apply the
   SELECT Count Query (with where clause) on the ItemList table

Please suggest which approach is better and why? I am more declined towards the second approach, and regarding efficency i guess both have same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option #1 will perform better for read operations because the count has already been aggregated.  The downside to this approach is that you must:

- Manually update this number yourself for every insert and delete across your application.
- Update this number every time an item is added to the list. If you're application write to read ratio is high it might not be worth the effort

Option #2 will perform better if you're application has more insert/deletes compared to reads.  The reason for this is that SQL Server only needs to calculate the count when it is needed.

I would suggest going with option #2 unless you have identified performance issues that would make you want to take a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Second approach is better from a data purity point of view. Let the data tell its own natural story - if you can work out how many lists an item is in by doing a quick `Select count(ListId), ItemID as CountOfLists from ItemList Group By ItemID` then it's a far more attractive option than having to find all the spots in the code that modify `ItemList` and make sure they update `Item.Count`

You'd consider the first option *only* if you were looking to denormalise/pre-aggregate the data for performance reasons. You've got to do extra work to make sure that the Count column in your Item table is always accurate (or, [eventually](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/04/14/quick-thoughts-on-eventual-consistency/) accurate)